Why was my suggested edit rejected?
With reference to this suggested edit, why did one of the reviewers select 'reject and edit' (the other reviewer approved the suggested edit), thus rejecting my edit and then apply the exact same edit I made and highlighted in the 'Edit Summary' with no other new edits (see this revision), while at the same time rejecting the minor edits I made to meet the six character minimum edit limit (which I also explained in the 'Edit summary')?
My edit summary was:

Fix typo (heart should be heard) and make minor edits to reach 6 characters.


Don't know; seems to be a mistake. Don't worry about it though.

Worth considering that the OP themself, @hippietrail, [listed as community] also rejected the edit, certainly not for fixing the typo but the other very minor edits: two commas and changing "where" for "whereas". Next time, in order to meet the minimum number of characters, just add extra spaces to the last sentence whenever a new line begins. For example, add one or two spaces after "English.", "them." and "check." The extra spaces are not rendered (if that's the right word), and will not mess up the formatting

Please don't bother making such trivial edits. It is a waste of reviewer time; you will achieve the same result faster with less effort overall by leaving a comment stating which changes/corrections are needed, from which someone with enough rep can make them directly.

In particular, using whitespace to fill up the six characters defeats the purpose of that limitation: it is a sign that you should not be making this edit at all, or finding useful changes to make besides this, or following the advice above and let someone else do it.
